# Filter a list of objects given a single object

Tags: c#, .net

I want a method that accepts a list of objects, and then the 'filter object' (which is the same type as the list of objects). I'm able to do it (inefficiently) on a small scale but also quite fixed - I'd like it to be a generic method so I can pass in the type so it can apply to anything.

Example:

```
public class Program {
    public void Main(string[] args) {
        var listOfObjects = new List<MyClass> {
            new MyClass { ID = 1, Name = "Object 1" },
            new MyClass { ID = 2, Name = "Object 2" },
            new MyClass { ID = 3, Name = "Object 2" }
        };
        var filter = new MyClass { Name = "Object 2" };

        // Should return only the first object in the list, since
        // the filter's Name = "Object 2", all items in the list
        // where the property equals "Object 2" will be filtered out
        var filteredList = FilterObjects(listOfObjects, filter);
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyTest {
    public List<MyClass> FilterObjects(List<MyClass> objects, MyClass filter) {
        // first check if the filter is just an empty new instance
        // if a user passes in an empty filter then they are not
        // filtering anything, therefore 
        if (filter == new MyClass()) return objects;

        var filteredList = new List<MyClass>();
        foreach (var item in objects) {
            // if this item passes the test for the filter
            // (check if any of the properties are equal to the
            // filter properties - if so, then this item is not
            // is not a match, and we cannot add it to the list)
            if (item.ID != filter.ID && item.Name != filter.Name)
                filteredList.Add(item);
            // What I want is a faster and more consolidated way of
            // checking all the properties.
        }
        return filteredList;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Is there any way to do this also using reflection?

EDIT2: Just wanted to clarify that my example here is just a simple template. I am working with an object that has 20+ properties and would love to not have to make a huge if statement if possible.

EDIT3: I should also mention that the filter object the user passes in can be incomplete, e.g. they can pass in a `MyClass` object without the ID (just the Name property) because when it reaches my Controller, that MyClass object will automagically fill in ID with a default value. I can check if it is a default value by creating a new instance of MyClass - `new MyClass()` and for every property, if it equals what the default value would be then ignore that property for filtering because the user didn't want that property filtered. But think of this concept on a larger scale where I have 20+ properties and a user wants to filter out all objects but ONLY wants to use 3 of those properties to filter from. The other 17+ properties will not have an equality check.

Comment: If the classes have specific rules (one per class) on how to compare them, then implement `IComparable<T>` and use it. You could use reflection, but the problem is that you have to have some rules to find out which properties have to match. In your example the filter object has its ID set to 0. How can the system know not to compare that? Alternatively use Linq instead

Comment: You said Linq. What method would be the best to use for this? Union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want are generic statements.

It isn't super straightforward but something like this should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> results, Filter filter)
    {
        var types = results.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var filter in filter.Filters)
        {
            Type type = results.GetType();
            filter.ColumnName = filter.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "");
            var pred = BuildPredicate<T>(filter.ColumnName, filter.FilterValue);
            if (filter.ColumnName != null && filter.FilterValue != null)
            {
                results = results.Where(w =>
                {                        
                    return w.GetType().GetProperty(filter.ColumnName).GetValue(w, null).ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.FilterValue.ToLowerInvariant());
                });
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

The filter object looks something like:

```
public class Filter
{
   public string ColumnName {get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
   //Other properties for Asc / Desc and more
}
```

And then on any List like List or List you would essentially do:

```
var results = MyList.Filter(new Filter() { ColumnName = "LastName"; Value = "Smith" });
```

which gets translated to a Function that if typed manually would look like:

```
var results = MyList.Where(w => w.LastName == "Smith");
```

This example however is rough, no type checking for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use methods already part of the `System.Generic.Collections` library.

```
 var filteredList= new List<MyClass>(listOfObjects);
 filteredList.RemoveWhere(n => n.Name == "Object 2");
```

If you want to use another class as your filter:

```
MyClass filter = new MyClass() {Name = "Object 2", Id=2 };
var filteredList= new List<MyClass>(listOfObjects);
filteredList.RemoveWhere(n => (n.Name == filter.Name || n.Id == filter.Id)); // you can modify predicate based on whatever you wish to compare
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, just what I was looking for. Now is there any way to consolidate the function statement so I don't have to write `n => n.Name1 == "blah" && n.Name2 == "blah" && n.Name3 == "blah"`... thanks for your help

Comment: @MattD not sure what your mean. This function iterates the list for you. so you would not have to do what your referring to if I understand correctly.

Comment: @MattD, if you neet to test for equality of all the properties of your class (it's not so clear from you original post), consider implementing an Equals method on the class itself

Comment: I can absolutely use a .Where() statement to do what I want, but what I was originally looking for is a method that takes a list of objects, and a filter object that - in the most efficient way possible - removes any element from that list if it doesn't match the filter criteria (i.e. any property in the object is equal to it's corresponding filter property)

Comment: @GianPaolo Good point, but I don't want a full equality check, because I want it so that the user can just pass in an object that only contains, say, 3 of the properties in an HttpPost request. That object will automatically generate the 'new instance' values for the remaining 17 properties. Those 17 properties will not be checked because the user never wanted those parts filtered in the first place

Comment: @MattD I mean the existing method does what your requirements are: your list is: filteredList and your filter is the parameter (predicate). This method is pretty efficient. Unless you must have a custom method to duplicate this, as Gian Paolo mentioned you can define IComparable for you custom objects but it you want to compare different properties each time thats what the predicate is for

Comment: Also if you want it to match any property just filter your predicate (e.g. (n => (n.Name == "Object 2" || n.Id == 1)).

Comment: @MattD in the Equals method, for every property, you can write something such `if (filter.SomeProperty != null && filter.SomeProperty != this.SomeProperty) return false` I'm assuming that al properties of `MyClass` are nullable (e.g. reference type or Nullable<SomeValueType>)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a custom `IsMatch` method:

```
static bool IsMatch (MyClass toTest, MyClass filter)
{
    if (filter.Prop1 != null // or whatever value means "skip this property"
        && filter.Prop1 == toTest.Prop1)
        return true;

    if (filter.Prop2 != null & filter.Prop2 == toTest.Prop2)
        return true;

    ...

    return false;
}
```

and then let Linq do the lookup for you:

```
List<MyClass> filtered = listOfObjects.Where(x => !IsMatch(x, filter)).ToList();
```

A unit test checking (with reflection) that this method is always up to date, checking all properties now and in future can be helpful in not introducing bugs when you add properties to the class